# Why this DFS way not working?

Tags: python, algorithm

Problem description:

Given a 2D grid, each cell is either a wall 'W', an enemy 'E' or empty '0' (the number zero), return the maximum enemies you can kill using one bomb.

The bomb kills all the enemies in the same row and column from the planted point until it hits the wall since the wall is too strong to be destroyed.

Note that you can only put the bomb at an empty cell.

```
Example:
For the given grid

0 E 0 0
E 0 W E
0 E 0 0

return 3. (Placing a bomb at (1,1) kills 3 enemies)
```

My DFS solution:

```
def maxKilledEnemies(grid):
    """
    :type grid: List[List[str]]
    :rtype: int
    """
    l_row, l_col = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    visited = [[False] * l_col for _ in range(l_row)] #using this array to avoid duplicate traverse.

    def dfs(i, j):
        if 0 <= i < l_row and 0 <= j < l_col and not visited[i][j]:
            visited[i][j] = True
            if grid[i][j] == 'W': #wall return 0
                return 0
            elif grid[i][j] == '0': #0 means we just ignore this cell and traverse it adjacents
                top_val = dfs(i - 1, j)
                down_val = dfs(i + 1, j)
                left_val = dfs(i, j - 1)
                right_val = dfs(i, j + 1)
                return left_val + right_val + top_val + down_val
            elif grid[i][j] == 'E': # Enemy and we add it by 1
                top_val = dfs(i - 1, j)
                down_val = dfs(i + 1, j)
                left_val = dfs(i, j - 1)
                right_val = dfs(i, j + 1)
                return left_val + right_val + top_val + down_val + 1
        return 0

    ret = [0]
    for i in range(l_row):
        for j in range(l_col):
            if not visited[i][j] and grid[i][j] == '0':
                val = dfs(i, j)
                ret[0] = max(val, ret[0])
    return ret[0]

Solution().maxKilledEnemies([["0","E","0","0"],["E","0","W","E"],["0","E","0","0"]]) #return 4 but expect 3.
```

The idea is quit simple that for every cell which num is 0, we traverse it by 4 
directions(Top/Down/Left/Right).

I know there are other ways to solve it more smarter. But I would like to figure out why my way not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three errors in your code:

- In each recursion step, you explore all possible directions. This makes your search behave like a flood-fill, but you want to start in all directions from the bomb location you're checking only. After that, recurse (or search iteratively) in the given direction.
- You don't check whether the possible bomb location is empty, so your code could place the bomb on an enemy.
- You don't reset the visited array between searches, so that effectively only cell (0, 0) is assessed.

One solution is to have two functions,

- one for the possible bomb location. Check here whether the cell is empty. If yes, count the victims by recursing north, east, south and west.
- One for the "rays" of the bomb. Travel in the given direction and count the enemies until you hit a wall. Because the ray travels in only one direction, you don't need the visited array any longer.

This isn't really depth first search, so instead of calling the second function recursively, you could just use loops.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the use of DFS is not a solution. When you use DFS you search all reachable spaces in the grid but for your question you should just search the directly horizontal or vertical spaces.
Ex: When using DFS at [0][0] you will find all enemies, not only the ones at [0][1] and [1][0].